# Neural Network regression on skewed variable

Tags: python, data-science

I have tried to build NN that would predict FIFA players values by their skills. The   The network is having trouble to predict when the values are high. I've Tried using boxcox transformation but it didn't helped much. Im using MSE as the loss function for the network, and the activation function is relu.
How can I improve my predictions?

Value distribution:
[image: Value distribution]

Comment: What happens if you try to predict the log of the value?

Comment: I use boxcox transformation  and predicted on transformed value. it helped a little bit. I still want better results. my MAE is 10 million and the network is off by a lot in the  high values.

Comment: The graph above shows the value distribution, and boxcox transformation might help if you were trying to model that. But, if I've understood the description, you're actually trying to model a function from "player skill" to "player value", which is likely to be a noisy exponential curve (which is why taking the log of the player value might linearise it, simplifying the function). Assuming you can combine the player skill into a single number, I'd recommend drawing the graph of skill vs. value to see how noisy the data is. You could also consider creating two models: low skill and high skill.